# Unable to catch javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException in my ejb

Tags: jboss7.x, java-ee-6, jboss-arquillian

I am using JBoss 7.1.1 for deployment, and junit 4.11 + arquillian 1.1.2 for testing.
I have following method in my @Stateless EJB.

```
public MyEntity create(MyEntity entity) {
    try {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Caught! " + e.getClass().getName());
    }
    return entity;
}
```

The entity **MyEntity** has field description annotated as follows:

```
    @Size(min = 1, max = 256)
    private String description;
```

If I pass an entity to create() which does not satisfy above constraint, I expect to see the message, but I do not see it. Instead, I get ***javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException***, somehow by-passing the try-catch block.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Because the exception ***javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException*** is generated after the create() method. What was I thinking!